# Rails 4 Active record circular dependency error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

These are my tables:

```
create_table :messages do |t|
  t.integer :type
  t.string :text
  t.datetime :sent_date
  t.string :sender
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :users do |t|
  t.integer :phone
  t.string :fullname
  t.string :profile_image
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :send_tos do |t|
  t.string :receiver
  t.belongs_to :message
  t.boolean :is_received
end
```

and these are the model classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :send_tos, :foreign_key => 'receiver'
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => 'sender'
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'sender'
  has_many :send_tos
end

class Send_to < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "receiver"
  belongs_to :message
end
```

When I run these commands on rails console:

```
m = Message.new
m.save
s = Send_to.new
s.message = m
s.save
m.send_tos
```

After command `m.send_tos` I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant
>   SendTo

Why am I getting this error? What should I do to change it?

Comment: Try changing the name of the `Send_to` class to `SendTo`. This follows the naming convention that Rails assumes for its relationships. The name of the file it is in should be `send_to.rb`

Comment: @Alex.Bullard can you write your comment as an answer

Comment: Hmm not totally sure why you're getting an empty collection. Is `s.save` returning true? What is returned from `s.message_id`?

Comment: yes it was something like that. I need to get the object from database befor calling `m.send_tos`. Calling `m = Message.first` fixed the problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name of the `Send_to` class to `SendTo`. This follows the naming convention that Rails assumes for its relationships. The name of the file it is in should be `send_to.rb`